# Azure Devops API: get latest action on the repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, git-commit, git-tag

I'm using Azure Devops Rest API and I'm trying to figure out the best way of getting the latest action timestamp(date) on the specific repository.

Now I'm trying to fetch commits and tags and check the action data there. But I see that azure doesn't support fetching the latest only, so I have to paginate through all tags, for example.

I'm using these endpoints:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

All this processing is pretty much heavy memory-wise, so I need something different.

Probably someone can suggest an idea of how it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to specify the `searchCriteria` when calling the REST API.

For example, to get the latest commit from a specific repository, see [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) for details.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.$top={searchCriteria.$top}&api-version=6.0
```

The following PowerShell for your reference:

```
Param(
    [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}",
    [string]$project = "Test0924",
    [string]$repoid = "e7ad43eb-ecad-4098-93b4-b63fdf88711a",
    [string]$user = "",
    [string]$token = "xxx"
)
    
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$searchCriteria = "$" + "top=1"

#Get the latest commit from a specific repo 
$Url = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoid/commits?searchCriteria.$searchCriteria&api-version=6.0" 

$commit = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
cls
$commit.value.committer | select name, email, date
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me to minimize data to fetch